# MySQL: Query to get some rows compulsory

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query which will give rows corresponding to some values compulsory whether its values is null or these values do not exist in the tables.

E.g.

```
SELECT spot_key, market,panel_member, SUM(weight) as TVR 
FROM break_minute_tvr_fixed b 
WHERE b.column1 in (1,3,4,2,3,4) 
  and b.section in (1,2,3,4) 
  and b.sex in (1,2) 
  and b.age in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
  and b.market in ('9')  
  and spot_key in ( '1:20141017:2129' )  
GROUP BY spot_key, market;
```

This will return rows as :

```
+-----------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
| spot_key        | market | panel_member        | TVR                |
+-----------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
| 1:20141017:2129 | 9      | 010583010102;7.2930 | 134.65280079841614 |
+-----------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now if I add another value to market list like say 300 which do not exist in the table itself then my query becomes :

```
SELECT spot_key, market,panel_member, SUM(weight) as TVR 
  FROM break_minute_tvr_fixed b 
 WHERE b.column1 in (1,3,4,2,3,4) 
   and b.section in (1,2,3,4) 
   and b.sex in (1,2) 
   and b.age in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
   and b.market in ('9','300')  
   and spot_key in ( '1:20141017:2129' )  
GROUP BY spot_key, market;
```

It gives me the same output as above . But I need something like below :

```
+-----------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
| spot_key        | market | panel_member        | TVR                |
+-----------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
| 1:20141017:2129 | 300    |                     |  0                 |
| 1:20141017:2129 | 9      | 010583010102;7.2930 | 134.65280079841614 |
+-----------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Did you try after removing `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: so there are no rows that have `market` = `300` in `break_minute_tvr_fixed`, but you want to show them in the results along with the `spot_key`?  Side question: why are you using in with only  1 `spot_key`?  can you have more than 1 spot_key?  if so what would would the desired output be?  all the pairings of `spot_key` and 'market` ?

Comment: yes @Doon You are right. We can have multiple spot_key in the "in"clause.
In that case I need all the combinations.

Comment: You received what seems to be a thorough answer from an experienced contributor on the same day that you asked this question, but you do not seem to have voted, accepted or commented. Thus, I have regretfully downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `left join`:

```
SELECT spot_key, m.market, panel_member, SUM(weight) as TVR 
FROM (SELECT '9' as market UNION ALL SELECT '300'
     ) LEFT JOIN
     break_minute_tvr_fixed b 
     ON b.market = m.market and
        b.column1 in (1,3,4,2,3,4) and
        b.section in (1,2,3,4) and
        b.sex in (1,2) and
        b.age in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and
        b.spot_key in ( '1:20141017:2129' )  
GROUP BY spot_key, market;
```

Of course `spot_key` will be `NULL`, unless you explicitly assign it a value:

```
SELECT '1:20141017:2129' as spot_key, m.market, panel_member, SUM(weight) as TVR
```